# Blocking users from browsing on Church Sound System Computer

Tags: windows-7, blocking

Anyone know of how to or an add-on that we can install to block users from browsing the internet when they are running the sound system computer at church? We want to make it so people can only search the net if they have a password other than the general log on. That way they can run the programs such as Easy Worship and Cool Edit Pro for service but cannot "browse" while in the sound room without permission. We are using Windows 7.

Comment: Use a group policy to only allow the applications you want to be started as a normal user.  It's called AppLocker

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on parental controls for the general log-on; see [this HowToGeek page](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10524/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-7/) for instructions. Go into Control Panel, select Parental Controls, select the general account, select "Allow and Block specific programs". The program you want to block is `IEXPLORE.EXE`.

Edited to add: If you have other browsers on the computer, you'll want to block them as well. Firefox is `FIREFOX.EXE`, Google Chrome is `CHROME.EXE`.

Comment: Please state the key points from the web page you are linking to. Link only answers are not the best way to answer on SU in case the link ever changes